# Vb.net - HtmlDocument freezes form

Tags: vb.net

I am making a source forge -latest file downloader and when I try to get the link the form freezes for a while(10-15 seconds)

This is my code:

```
Private Function SourceForgeGetDirectUri(Uri As String) As String
    Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load(Uri) 'loads the website
    Dim aHref As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@class='direct-download']") 'finds the a href of the direct download
    Dim DirectLink = aHref.GetAttributeValue("href", "") ' gets the link

    Return DirectLink
End Function
```

What I have to do to stop this freezing ?

Comment: after it completes the task, do it work like normal again?

Comment: Yes, but is there a method to not freeze the whole form ? @Werdna

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a backgroundworker Code:

```
Private Sub SourceForgeDownload_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles SourceForgeDownload.DoWork
    SourceForgeDirectLink = SourceForgeGetDirectUri("https://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/latest/download")
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        Dim wc As New WebClient()
        AddHandler wc.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf wc_Changed
        AddHandler wc.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf wc_Completed
        wc.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(SourceForgeDirectLink), My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory + "filename.exe")
    End If
End Sub
```